# C double pointer's array notation equivalence

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

If I have the following double pointer and I use it in an array form, which of the mentioned pointer forms is it equivalent to?

```
char** argv = malloc(2*sizeof(char*));

//argv[0] == (argv + 0), *(argv + 0), or (*argv + 0)?

//Same way, what would argv[0][0] be equivalent to in terms of *(*(argv +i)+j), etc.?
```

Comment: Your second comment is correct, and contains the answer to the first. Assuming of course that your code has the additional `malloc` calls to initialize the two pointers that you allocated with the first `malloc` call.

Comment: Could you please help me understand why I need to malloc twice? So if I malloc for char ** argv, it is not enough for char * argv? I also need to malloc for char *argv?

Comment: `argv+0` is equivalent to `argv` (obviously). `*argv+0` is equivalent to `*argv` (also obviosly). `argv` is not equivalent to `*argv` (very obviously).

Comment: You allocated space for two pointers: `2*sizeof(char*)`. Now each of those pointers needs to point to something, e.g. `argv[0] = malloc(20);` Without the additional `mallocs`, you have a one dimensional array of pointers. With the additional `mallocs`, you have the equivalent of a two-dimensional array of `char`.

Comment: so argv is the same as argv[0]? and if i print argv[0], I will get the address of the pointer that argv points to?

Comment: No, `argv` is a *pointer-to-a-pointer-to-char*. `argv[0]` is a *pointer-to-char*. The answer to your second question depends on what you mean by print. You need to show the `printf` that you're talking about.

Comment: thanks @user3386109, I didn't understand the double malloc and now it makes sense.

Comment: printf("argv is %p", argv); how can i printf this value using array notation?

Comment: Now `*argv` *is* equivalent to `argv[0]`. By the same token, `**argv` is equivalent to `argv[0][0]`. `*(argv+N)` is equivalent to `argv[N]` etc. It should not be difficult to understand `argv[N][M]`.

Comment: it makes sense now. Thank you.

Comment: `X[Y]` means `*(X+Y)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `//argv[0] == (argv + 0), *(argv + 0), or (*argv + 0)?`

Well here both `*(argv + 0)` and `(*argv + 0)` are both equivalent to `argv[0]`. This can be easily know by printing the output. You can do something like this:

```
char** argv = malloc(2*sizeof(char*));

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    argv[i] = malloc(1);
}

//printing the values:
printf("%p == %p\n", argv[0], argv + 0);
printf("%p == %p\n", argv[0], *(argv + 0));
printf("%p == %p\n", argv[0], *argv + 0);
```

**output:**

```
0x8e84018 == 0x8e84008 //not equal
0x8e84018 == 0x8e84018 //same
0x8e84018 == 0x8e84018 //same
```

see here for complete example: https://ideone.com/DDXuI9

it's not true in the case of `(argv + 0)` because `(argv + 0)` points to the address of the `char** argv` itself whereas `argv[0]` points to the address of the first element *(which of the type `char*`)*